# how to port my game for android in sfml

Tags: android, sfml

i am a c++ programmer , and I want to develop games . I chose sfml , because I wanted to see what happens behind the scene better . I have an idea to make , and the desired platform is mobile devices(android , ios) . I have seen that sfml , support for touch and other capabilities of mobile devices , but I have no idea , how I can write a code , that works on all of them .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFML still does not officially support Android development as you can see on their official website (http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php).

> With SFML, your application can compile and run out of the box on the most common operating systems: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and **soon Android & iOS**.

However, there is a recently updated tutorial on how to build SFML for Android on Github: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Building-SFML-for-Android. But since Android is not officially supported you will probably run into many problems.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions.